# Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy on multipart FormData inclusion of "lang"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

In a Spring Boot 1.5.9 application, I have the following `LocaleResolver`:

```java
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver acceptHeaderLocaleResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver() {
            @Override
            public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
                String locale = request.getParameter("lang");
                return locale != null
                        ? org.springframework.util.StringUtils.parseLocaleString(locale)
                        : super.resolveLocale(request);
            }
        };
        acceptHeaderLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(webMvcProperties.getLocale());
        return acceptHeaderLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
```

For some reason, I have a side effect, when I `POST` a multipart form data that include a key named `lang`, then I have the following error:

```
Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy
```

Why and how can I fix that in order to be able to use `form` in my forms datas ?